# How to properly read a CDATA section in java using SAX parser

Tags: java, xml, parsing, sax, cdata

I have a XML in the following format.

```
<student>
   <class>&lt;![CDATA[4B]]&gt;</class>
</student>
```

I am parsing this XML with SAX parser.

While parsing I am getting the output as:

```
class:>[CDATA[4B]]<
```

How can I handle the < adn > in SAX.
Is there any way of converting them to < and > before giving it to the parser or can we handle them using SAX only?

Comment: A partially escaped CDATA section is not a CDATA section. The output you get is the correctly parsed output of the given XML. If you want to properly read a CDATA section using SAX, the input needs to contain an actual CDATA section in the first place. Perhaps rephrase the question to reflect what you actually want to do?

Comment: Downvoted for not showing us your code.

Comment: @StefanHaustein thanks. You directed me to the correct direction. I used StringEscapeHandler.unescapehtml to unescape the < and >. Then gave it to sax parser, it parsed it properly. Sorry for not give the code. Will keep it in mind next time.  Thanks a lot anyways for the help.

Comment: Note that this is quite dangerous. Attackers now potentially can insert any xml anywhere in your document, and special characters in text content may break parsing. Example: <class>&lt;class/&gt;</class> will break parsing if you pre-process your XML this way. You should try to find the root cause of this problem. Perhaps the content of class is XML, too, and you need to run a secondary parser on that?

Comment: Actually the xml is being generated uisng JaxB. Hence we are getting the CDATA like that. There is a escapeharacterHandler class in JAXB which can be used after generation of XML but it is java 8 compatible. I require something that is java 7 compatible.